# Is there an SSL library that allows me to add and access extensions and the certificate data?

Tags: tls, openssl

The subject (sort of) says it all...

Is there a TLS library (other than OpenSSL which does everything :-) ) that allows me to:

1. Add my own extensions to the TLS
2. Get the certificate data so I can make a certificate fingerprint

What I'm trying to do is have a TLS setup, where the client passes a URL as an extension, and, the client can get at the certificate so I can create a hash as a fingerprint that I can use as a unique ID?

It would allow me to pass meta-data along with the TLS setup to allow the server to fetch data outside of the TLS session.

Comment: You might want to check out [ucspi-ssl](https://www.fehcom.de/ipnet/ucspi-ssl.html).  This set of tools includes sslserver which can be used to build a server that accepts SSL/TLS connections, and sslclient which can be used to build a client that is able to initiate SSL/TLS connections.  Both provide access to the certificate used to secure the connection.

Comment: *"other than OpenSSL"* - why this explicit exclusion, especially since OpenSSL seems to do what you need? This sounds like you have some specific requirements which exclude OpenSSL. But these might also apply to other libraries, so you need to specify these requirements. For example what about LibreSSL which is a fork of OpenSSL?

Comment: Most if not all TLS connectors allow access to the certificate, usually through some kind of  context that is delivered when the handshake succeeds. As for the extensions; extensions to do **what** exactly?

Comment: I was hoping to add a new URL into the certificate.  Let's call it IdentityService which points to a URL.  The receiving server can use this URL to get additional information..   Assume my client cert had this extra attribute, my server should be able to retrieve it and the service pointed to by the URL should be able to get the server's cert fingerprint.

Comment: I had avoided openssl because I was told it was big, complex and convulted to use -- I was looking at the "new" SSLs like Boring and BearSSL.   I get it -- use something ucsp-ssl and see how it's done and build off of those concepts.....

Comment: OP, You can add custom fields to a CSR by adding these in a config file, then use the `-config` option with `openssl req` to create a CSR containing these fields.  Widely trusted CA's like Verisign, Let's Encrypt, GeoTrust etc., will probably not include these fields in the signed cert, but if you self-sign or run your own CA, then these fields will end up in the signed certificate.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36007663/how-to-add-custom-field-to-certificate-using-openssl for more info.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/meixler/installing-configuring-and-running-ucspi-ssl-sslserver for info on getting up and running with ucspi-ssl sslserver.